# Python quotient vs remainder

Tags: python, modulo

The python 2.6 docs state that `x % y` is defined as the remainder of x / y (http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex). I am not clear on what is really occurring though, as:

```
for i in range(2, 11):
    print 1.0 % i
```

prints "1.0" ten times, rather than "0.5, 0.333333, 0.25" etc. as I expected (1/2 = 0.5, etc).

Comment: you are confusing quotient and remainder.

Comment: Perhaps I need to hit wikipedia, but here's how I'm using those words: Quotient is the whole-number portion from the result, and remainder is the fractional portion. E.g., for 8.0/3, the quotient = 2, and the remainder = 0.6666. Is that false?

Comment: yes, that is false. the remainder is 2. it is what _remains_ after you have repeatedly subtracted the subtrahend from the minuend (until you can't anymore)

Comment: sorry, you subtract the divisor form the dividend, of course

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you can get the result you want by doing something like this:

```
for i in range(2, 11):
    print 1.0*(1 % i) / i
```

This computes the (integer) remainder as explained by others. Then you divide by the denominator again, to produce the fractional part of the quotient.

Note that I multiply the result of the modulo operation by 1.0 to ensure that a floating point division operation is done (rather than integer division, which will result in 0).

Answer (score 10):

Modulo is performed in the integer context, not fractional (remainders are integers). Therefore:

```
1 % 1  = 0  (1 times 1 plus 0)
1 % 2  = 1  (2 times 0 plus 1)
1 % 3  = 1  (3 times 0 plus 1)

6 % 3 = 0  (3 times 2 plus 0)
7 % 3 = 1  (3 times 2 plus 1)
8 % 3 = 2  (3 times 2 plus 2)

etc
```

> *How do I get the actual remainder of x / y?*

By that I presume you mean doing a regular floating point division?

```
for i in range(2, 11):
    print 1.0 / i
```

Comment: The reminders are not necessarily integers, for example 2.5 % 2 = 0.5. It just happens to be that the correct answer to 1.0 % x is 1.0, for every x > 1.

Comment: -1 because it's incorrect to say remainders are integers. In Python, `%` works on floating-point numbers and can give a non-integer result. (JavaScript too.)

Answer (score 4):

You've confused [division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)) and [modulus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).

"0.5, 0.333333, 0.25" etc. as I expected (1/2 = 0.5, etc)."

That's the result of *division*.

Not *modulus*.

Modulus (`%`) is the remainder left over after integer division.

Your sample values are simple division, which is the `/` operator.  Not the `%` operator.

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't dividing 1 by an number larger than it result in 0 with remainder 1?

The number theorists in the crowd may correct me, but I think modulus/remainder is defined only on integers.

Comment: 1 divided by 4 results in 0 with a remainder of 0.25.

Comment: Nooo...1.0 / 4.0 = 0.25.  1 / 4 = 0 remainer 1.  I don't think mod does what you think it does.

Comment: Interpreted in the integer context, 1 % anything greater than it should give 1, so actually the OP's program is working perfectly, albeit not what he wants.

Answer (score 3):

We can have 2 types of division, that we can define through the return types:

Float: a/b. For example: 3/2=1.5

```
def division(a,b):
    return a/b
```

Int: a//b and a%b. For example: 3//2=1 and 3%2=1

```
def quotient(a,b):
    return a//b
def remainder(a,b):
    return a%b
```